Blender SVG points not Filling properly
So when I import an SVG Image some of the points dont fill in I know its a blender issue because when I try it in inkscape it works fine.


Okay so I figured it out, I just turned up the resolution preview and it fixed it on this one, I had this happen on another svg and I turned the resolution down that fixed that one. Hope this helps anyone who may be also having this issue.
